# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(i)[s -> e] : Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an Angular Application and I have used lazy Loading. When I am serving the application using ng serve --aot there is no error in the and also when I do ng build --prod still there is no error. But When I upload the build files in my hosting and trying to navigate from HOMEPAGE (https://pawsticks.rahuls.co.in) to LOGIN (https://pawsticks.rahuls.co.in/login) page there is an error in the terminal shows -

Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(i)[s -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[s -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!.

I am not getting it from where the error is occurring.

[image]

APP Module -

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { FeatureModule } from '@/modules/featured';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
import { AppComponent } from '@/app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,         // NGX Spinner
    FeatureModule.forRoot()   //Injecting Feature Module as ROOT Module
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Feature Module:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

//Importing HTTP Intercepter and services
import { HTTPInterceptorProvider } from '@/core/_HTTP-interceptor';
import { AjaxService, AuthTokenService, CommonHelperService } from '@/core/_services';

import { SummaryPipe } from '@/core/_pipes';

//Externel Plugins Modules
import { ShowHidePasswordModule } from 'ngx-show-hide-password';
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
import { ImageCropperModule } from 'ngx-image-cropper';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';


//Success Error Component, Password Strength Component, Animated Numbers Component
import {
  SuccessErrorComponent,
  PasswordStrengthBarComponent,
  AnimatedNumbersComponent,
} from '@/modules/shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SuccessErrorComponent,
    PasswordStrengthBarComponent,
    AnimatedNumbersComponent,
    //Pipes used are listed here
    SummaryPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgxIntlTelInputModule,
    ShowHidePasswordModule, // Show Hide Password Plugin Import
    ImageCropperModule,  // Image cropper Module
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(), //Bootstrap Datepicker Plugin
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    NgxPaginationModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  exports: [
    SuccessErrorComponent,
    PasswordStrengthBarComponent,
    AnimatedNumbersComponent,

    SummaryPipe,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxIntlTelInputModule,
    ImageCropperModule,  // Image cropper Module
    BsDatepickerModule, //Bootstrap Datepicker Plugin
    BsDropdownModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    ShowHidePasswordModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        HTTPInterceptorProvider,
        AjaxService,
        AuthTokenService,
        CommonHelperService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

App Routing Module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomPreloadingStrategy } from './preloading-strategy';
import { AuthGuard, SecureOuterPagesGuard } from "@/core/_guards";

// Home page of the application
import { IndexComponent } from '@/modules/index/index.component';

// Authentication and Authorization Components
import { 
  LoginComponent, 
  RegisterComponent, 
  VerifyAccountComponent, 
  VerifyAccountStatusComponent,
  ForgetPasswordComponent,
  ResetPasswordComponent 
} from '@/modules/auth';

// Session Timeout, Page Not Found and Interner Server Error Components
import {
  SessionTimeOutComponent,
  PageNotFoundComponent,
  InternalServerErrorComponent
} from '@/modules/shared';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'verify-account',
    component: VerifyAccountComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'verify-account-status',
    component: VerifyAccountStatusComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'forget-password',
    component: ForgetPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password',
    component: ResetPasswordComponent,
    canActivate: [SecureOuterPagesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { preload: true }
  },
  { 
    path: 'internal-server-error', 
    component: InternalServerErrorComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: 'page-not-found', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  },
  {
    path: 'session-time-out',
    component: SessionTimeOutComponent
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloadingStrategy })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [CustomPreloadingStrategy]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [
  IndexComponent,
  LoginComponent, 
  RegisterComponent, 
  VerifyAccountComponent, 
  VerifyAccountStatusComponent,
  ForgetPasswordComponent,
  ResetPasswordComponent,
  SessionTimeOutComponent,
  PageNotFoundComponent,
  InternalServerErrorComponent,
]
```

Comment: Where is your API call hits from, component.ts?

Comment: Maybe the issue is in your bootstraping code. Anyway, you can test the build artifacts directly. `npm i -g http-server` `cd dist-path` `http-server .`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad after the command you have said, can i be able to run the index.html in the dist folder locally?

Comment: @DevGo I have  AjaxService to make all the api calls to backend.

Comment: Yes, it's just a very basic local server. If you need data from your backend API simply to navigate from home to login, then you would need to run your backend locally or enable cors on your production server.

Comment: @SwagataAdhikary Agree... But without seeing your code where its called from, how can we know the issue... There might be something missing from component.. You have to define your service in constructor as private....

Comment: Better you create a stakblitz

Comment: @DevGo i have found the problem. The problem is happening because of this plugin 
ShowHidePasswordModule. I am using it as directive in my password input to show or hide the password. As I have not used it in the declarations array that is why may be the error occurring.  

How can i import it in declarations array. I am imported it as a module in my featured moduel.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-show-hide-password